# Maximum, over all unit vectors, of directional derivative CALCULUS 3

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Given $ f(x,y,z) = x^2 +3xz + \dfrac{y^3}{3}$ I'm asked to find the maximum value, ***over all unit vectors,*** of $D_{u} f(1,2,-1)$.

Attempt :
$$ \nabla f = \langle f_x , f_y, f_z \rangle = \langle 2x + 3z, y^2 , 3x \rangle $$
$$D_u f = || \nabla f(1,2,-1)|| = || (-1,4,-3)|| = \sqrt{26}   $$

I feel like i'm  missing a step somewhere, particularly something concerning the " all unit vectors". 
Thank you for help.

Comment: $D_u f  = \nabla f \cdot u$, with $u$ a unit vector, so that is the step to include

Comment: Yes, but given that the max direction $u=\nabla f(P)/\|\nabla f(P)\|$, you just get $D_uf=\|\nabla f(P)\|$. Nothing is formally missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $D_u f(P) = \nabla f(P) \cdot u$, so
$$
    D_u f(P) = \Vert \nabla f(P) \Vert \, \Vert u \Vert \,\cos\theta
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between $\nabla f(P)$ and $u$.  Remember $\Vert u \Vert =1$ and $|\cos\theta|\leq 1$.  So the maximum value of $D_u f(P)$, over all unit vectors $u$, occurs when $u$ points in the same direction as $\nabla f(P)$ (i.e., $\cos\theta =1 \implies \theta = 0$).  In this case, $D_u(P) = \Vert \nabla f(P) \Vert$.